# drag and drop sorting of rows in titanium alloy app

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to implement drag and drop sorting of rows in my titanium alloy app using JavaScript for Android, iOS and Windows platforms. So far, I am able to drag and drop a View using touch events. But I have already encountered some problems such as animation not being smooth etc. I also need to build an algorithm to sort the rows. I have already searched through the appcelerator archive, couldn't find a good approach there.

Can someone assist me with its implementation? Are there any resources that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some modules that can help you with drag and drop:

e.g. https://github.com/viezel/TiDraggable and https://github.com/animecyc/TiDraggable

These are forks of https://github.com/pec1985/TiDraggable/network so make sure to check that page to see if there are newer forks.

What animation are you talking about when you say "not smooth"? It depends on the content of the row you are dragging. If there are to many items to move it would be better to create a "ghost" item (just a view with a colored background) and move this around. Once you let go you remove/add your original container again.

**About the sorting:**

you have to implement it yourself. But basically you know which element you are dragging (give every item an id) and then find out at which position you are dragging the item to (by y-position or check the element which is under your finger). Then just move your item at that place. Or rearrange a json file and assign it to the table/listview once you finished dragging.

**ListView on iOS**

If you are using a listview on iOS you can use "canMove" (https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListItem-property-canMove)

> Specifies if the item can be reordered within the list view by a user initiated action.

But it's only available on iOS. So for a cross platform way you have to create your own sorting.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use https://github.com/animecyc/TiDraggable, but couldn't because we have implement drag and drop on Windows too. I have started working on it with touch events.